# RestClient for Ruby with smarkets.com api - Curl to RestClient

Tags: ruby, rest, curl, rest-client

the api I'm working with is [here](http://apidocs.s3-external-3.amazonaws.com/guide/getting_started.html):

I'm able to log in fine and get back an auth token, but cant figure out how to do anything that requires a token. I get back a forbidden response when I try to get or post a private URL.

they give an example of the request that needs to be sent using curl:

curl \
        --header 'Authorization: UserLogin token="kk5lvKJG1FohVbS3kcHllyTshdcBKX4FpFAKFnx_Eh0IYYpXN3Hg6HZLceXuYt7V52mCcdUk5i_GUMc~"' \
        -X POST \
        'https://api.smarkets.com/v1/users/renew'

My question is: how would one send an equivalent request using the RestClient library in Ruby? I have a feeling that i'm messing up the header because the header in RestClient is all {:key => 'value'} pairs and I don't see how that would translate to the header given in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an HTTP request, headers are key/value pairs separated by a `:`, so the header pair that you need to send is:

```
:authorization => 'UserLogin token="kk5lvKJG1FohVbS3kcHllyTshdcBKX4FpFAKFnx_Eh0IYYpXN3Hg6HZLceXuYt7V52mCcdUk5i_GUMc~"'
```

So, to reproduce the request you give in your example:

```
RestClient.post 'https://api.smarkets.com/v1/users/renew', '', :authorization => 'UserLogin token="kk5lvKJG1FohVbS3kcHllyTshdcBKX4FpFAKFnx_Eh0IYYpXN3Hg6HZLceXuYt7V52mCcdUk5i_GUMc~"'
```